# How to match such kind of strings using and in regex?

Tags: java, regex

How to make an `or` and `and` together in Regex.

We can do this in regex `(Boo)|(l30o)` and list all permutations which basically beats the purpose of using regex. Here or is being used.

I want to match `B` in any form, `O` in any form twice. Something like, `[(B)|(l3)][0 o O]{2}`. But, in this form, it matches `(0O` too.

O twice matching isn't a problem.

B when trying to match with multiple character match is a problem along with single character match.

Should match:
Boo
b0o
l300
I3oO
B00

etc.

All words which look like Boo, i.e., `b - {B,b,l3,I3,i3}` and `o - {O, o, 0}`;

Comment: Could you please clarify with some examples of what you need to match/not to match?

Comment: @Tarun Maganti,
  [0 o O]{2} will match 0O as you are saying you want to match o in any form twice then what's wrong with it ?

Comment: O has no problem. @RizwanM.Tuman

Comment: Don't use `[(B)|(l3)]` but `(B|l3)`. `[...]` is a character class and thus any `(` inside will be assumed to be a literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `(?:[bB]|[lIi]3)[0Oo]{2}`:

- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group
- `[...]` is a character class, i.e. any character inside it (except `-` depending on the position) will be assumed to be meant literally (i.e. `[iIl]` matches `i`, `L` *or* `l`, while `[(B)|(l3)]` wouldn't do what you think it does: it matches any of `(`, `B`, `)`, `|`, `l` or `3`).
- `|` means "or" and matches entire sequences
- `{...}` is a numeric quantifier (i.e. `{2}` means exactly twice)

You could also use `(?i)` at the start of your expression to make it case-insensitive, i.e. the expression would then be `(?i)(?:b|[li]3)[0o]{2}`.

Comment: What if I want to limit character insensitivity to a part of string?

Comment: @TarunMaganti in that case you could use `(?i)` to start the case insensitive part and `(?-i)` to end it, e.g. `(?i)(?:b|[li]3)(?-i)[0o]{2}` to not allow `O` in a match.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following

```
(B|b|l3|I3|i3)[0oO]{2}
```

You can try it online at https://regex101.com/r/gLA6N2/3

Comment: What is the comma for?

Comment: Oops, Typo! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
(B|b|l3|I3|i3)(O|o|0)+
```

() is a group

| is an or

+ is a quantifier for {1,} which means 1 or more

Comment: Where is there a situation where I use []. Something like [B (l3)]. Why does it fail in a situation like this?

Comment: character classes are usually a convenient way to specify ranges of characters in an ascii table eg. [a-z]. If you use only single letters there should be no difference between [adz] and (a|d|z). The character class is just syntactic sugar if you want to match single character in a set (it's 2 times as short for bigger classes). [B (l3)] if parsed at all, would match (B| |\(|l|3|\)) you most likely would have to escape the \(\) to be validly parse at all.